# get_object_or_404 while using multi-table(?) Inheritance in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, inheritance

Currently working on Django 1.6, MySQL and South:

I recently starting working with inheritance and Django models.

Wondering if anyone has run into an issue where running get_object_or_404 from django.shortcuts yields 404 with the message no matches found, but writing the query normally using model.objects.get(pk=###) will yield a single answer.

I want to emphasize that the model we are inheriting is not an abstract model.

Using the code below as a sample:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, default=None,)
    trunk_size = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    fleet_leader = models.ForeignKey("Car", related_name='car_fleet', null=True, default=None)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Car"
        verbose_name_plural = "Cars"

Bigcar(Car):
    extra_storage_size = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Car"
        verbose_name_plural = "Cars"
```

So if I make the query:

```
get_object_or_404(Car, pk=123)
```

Assuming that the Car data entry with row or primary key 123 exists, I would not get any results, however the entry

```
Car.objects.get(pk=123)
```

Would yield a result.

So I'm wondering if anyone knows what's going on with these queries? Am I missing some setting or code that I should implement following the inheritance being used? I've looked into the Django documentation and most of the emphasis is on abstract model inheritance usage.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken South does not support Django version 1.7 and upwards and problem may be in it.

Comment: please post this as two questions.

Comment: @Edrw My mistake, I was using 1.6, not 1.8